# Is it possible to prove Lorentz transformations in 3 space Dimensions using just simple vectors

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, vectors, inertial-frames

I mean like in this figure [image: lorentz via vectors]

and the standard  inputs

1. speed of light is equal to $c$ in all reference frames.
2. Laws of physics are the same in all directions

Is this *right* or *enough*  to derive?

I think the answer would come out to be

$$\vec{r^{\prime}} = \vec{r} - (1 - \gamma)(\hat{\beta} \bullet \vec{r} ) \hat{\beta} - \gamma \vec{\beta} ct 
$$

and
$$
ct^{\prime} = \gamma ( - \vec{\beta} \bullet \vec{r} + ct)
$$

Comment: What does "proving Lorentz transformations" mean?

Comment: deriving the Lorentz transformations

Comment: Is there a time direction, or are you talking about 3d space (and not 2+1 space-time )?

Comment: 3 D space directions

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations#From_group_postulates. Note that, according to it, both Galilean and Lorentz are possible, being Galilean discarded in an experimental way.

Comment: Did you check it in special cases? e.g. $\hat\beta \cdot \hat r=1$ and $\hat\beta \cdot \hat r=0$ ? Then, use linearity for a general setup. Presumably, this has a Euclidean analogue that could also be checked.

Comment: Yes robphy, I have checked it. It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression looks correct.

Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics, 3e derives the following equations (11.19) on p.525.
$$
\begin{align}
x_0'&=\gamma(x_0-\vec \beta \cdot \vec x)
\\
\vec x'&=\vec x+\frac{(\gamma-1)}{\beta^2}(\vec \beta\cdot \vec x)\vec\beta-\gamma\vec\beta x_0
\end{align}
$$
(See also equation (11.21) on p. 357 in the 1962 edition.)

Those equations above are also derived in Goldstein's Classical Mechanics, 2e as Eqs. (7-11 and 7-12) on p. 278-280. The result is only quoted as Eq. (7-9) in the 3rd edition on p. 281.

Fahnline in his "A covariant four-dimensional expression for Lorentz transformations"
(Am.J.Phy., 50, 9, pp. 818-821 (1982). https://doi.org/10.1119/1.12748 )
quotes the above equations from the earlier editions of the texts above,
then
derives a covariant expression [which I haven't checked] using 4-vectors as:
$$
x'^\mu = x^\mu+ 
\frac{
[\hat n\cdot \tilde x-(2\gamma +1)\hat v\cdot \tilde x]n^\mu+(\hat n\cdot \tilde x+\hat v\cdot\tilde x)\hat v^\mu
}{1+\gamma}
$$
where $\hat n$ and $\hat v=(\tilde v/c)$ are the [unit] 4-velocities,
and $\hat v \cdot \hat v = -1$
and $\gamma= -\hat n\cdot \hat v$
using the $(-,+,+,+)$ signature convention.
$\hat n$ is essentially the time-axis (the 4-velocity of our frame) and $\hat v$ is the 4-velocity of the other frame.

Comment: Can you also help me derive it using the figire as given in the question and other details mentioned in the question?

Comment: @TejasShetty Sorry, the end of this semester is extremely busy. It might help other readers if you could explain your diagram and, at least, show some progress toward the solution you seek. (Did you go through one of the textbook proofs? It could help you obtain a proof in the style that you seek.)